# How to display a loading view until a new screen is opened?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple screen (`MainActivity`) that does some action upon clicking a button.

1. When the action is not loading, the button to trigger it is displayed.
2. When the action is loading, a full screen loading view is displayed.
3. When the action is loaded (finished), a new screen is opened (`SecondActivity`).

The problem is that there is quite a big delay before the new screen is opened and the button from 1. is displayed for quite a long time.
Ideally I would like the loading view to remain there till the new screen is opened but when the back button is clicked, the screen should be in the initial state.

How can I achieve that?

---

**MainActivity:**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val state by viewModel.stateStream.collectAsState()

            if (state == MainViewModel.State.LOADED) {
                SideEffect {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
                    viewModel.resetState()
                }
            }

            Scaffold {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    when (state) {
                        MainViewModel.State.LOADING -> CircularProgressIndicator()
                        else -> Button(viewModel::doAction) { Text("Do action") }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val stateStream = MutableStateFlow(State.IDLE)

    fun doAction() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stateStream.value = State.LOADING
            delay(1000)
            stateStream.value = State.LOADED
        }
    }

    fun resetState() {
        stateStream.value = State.IDLE
    }

    enum class State {
        IDLE, LOADING, LOADED
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```kotlin
class SecondActivity : ComponentActivity()
```

Comment: My suggestion is to move the loading logic and the spinner into the `SecondActivity`. As soon as the user taps the button the `SecondActivity` opens and shows the loading spinner view and does whatever the task in background. If the user taps back, `finish()` it. It's easier to manage that way.

Comment: If your second activity takes a long time to load, you're likely doing too much work on the main thread. You haven't provided the code for the second activity, so I can't help you with identifying what that might be. Also, it might be a good idea to reevaluate whether you need a second activity. Initialising Compose can take time, so switching between activities might be slower because of that too, depending on device. Also, when using Compose always make sure to test the performance in release, because Compose does a lot of extra work in debug to allow for previews and the like.